# get requests to localhost is working from android app while post requests giving error with unexpected code 500

Tags: android, rest, laravel-5, android-volley

Facing problem to access my localhost web services. Get Requests are working fine from mobile app and postman both while post requests are not working when call from android mobile app but working fine with postman.
I am using IP of my machine to access web service.

Comment: Please post the code from where you are calling the API and the code where you have implemented the code for Volley request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i resolved the issue it was due to issue of code in Multipart Request of Volley and Permission of Network State was needed in manifest for calling localhost web service from android application.
Hope it helps anyone who face the same issue